# Conectar a una base de datos IBM DB2 desde ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, as400

Necesito acceder a una base de datos AS400 db2 desde una aplicación ASP .Net 5 o Core.

Intente con entity framework a través de los siguientes paquetes

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/IBMDB2EF

Siguiendo la documentación de esta página:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/ibm/index.html

Pero no funcionó, me presentaba errores del proveedor, no se si estaba haciendo las cosas correctamente, si tienen algún ejemplo sería genial.

En última instancia usaría ADO clásico, agrego el código usado.

project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"EntityFramework.IBMDataServer": "7.0.0-beta1",
. . .
```

},

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddViews()
            .AddRazorViewEngine();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddDb2()
            .AddDbContext<DB2.Models.Users.UserContext>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    }
```

User.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DB2.Models.Users
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string CODCOL { get; set; }
        public string CLACOL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using IBM.Data.Entity;

namespace DB2.Models.Users
{
    public class UserContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseDb2(@"Server=x;Database=x;password=x;uid=x;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }        
    }
}
```

UserRepository.cs

```
using System.Linq;

namespace DB2.Models.Users
{
    public class UserRepository: IUserRepository
    {
        private UserContext _context;

        public UserRepository(UserContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void pass()
        {
            var x = _context.User.First();           
        }
    }
}
```

Compila perfecto, una vez que lo ejecuto, me aparace un error en la línea:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  FileName=IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: IBM.Data.DB2, Version= 9.7.4.4, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7c307b91aa13d208
LOG: Fusion is hosted.Check host about this assembly.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly ibm.data.db2, version= 9.7.4.4, culture= neutral, publickeytoken= 7c307b91aa13d208, processorarchitecture= x86.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly ibm.data.db2, version= 9.7.4.4, culture= neutral, publickeytoken= 7c307b91aa13d208, processorarchitecture= msil.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly ibm.data.db2, version= 9.7.4.4, culture= neutral, publickeytoken= 7c307b91aa13d208.
WRN: Host assembly store does not contain this assembly.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/IBM.Data.DB2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/IBM.Data.DB2/IBM.Data.DB2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/IBM.Data.DB2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/IBM.Data.DB2/IBM.Data.DB2.EXE.

  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.
 Source=EntityFramework.IBMDataServer
 StackTrace:
       at IBM.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.Db2SqlConnection.CreateDbConnection()
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
       at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at DB2.Models.Users.UserRepository.pass() in D:\Proyectos\MVC\NSEL\DB2\src\DB2\Models\Users\UserRepository.cs:line 16
       at DB2.Controllers.HomeController.test() in D:\Proyectos\MVC\NSEL\DB2\src\DB2\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 33
  InnerException:
```

(Actualización)
Instale el driver: IBM Data Server Driver Package y me muestra un error diferente al anterior

```
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception was unhandled by user code
ErrorCode=-2147467259
HResult=-2147467259
Message=ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "192.168.128.5".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Source=IBM.Data.DB2
StackTrace:
    at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
    at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.Open()
    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
    at DB2.Models.Users.UserRepository.pass() in D:\Proyectos\MVC\NSEL\DB2\src\DB2\Models\Users\UserRepository.cs:line 16
    at DB2.Controllers.HomeController.test() in D:\Proyectos\MVC\NSEL\DB2\src\DB2\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 33
InnerException:
```

Comment: podrias publicar los errores de los que hablas igual ayuda a otros usuari@s a solucionar tu problema. Saludos

Comment: SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Acabo de editar su pregunta para añadir el código que usted dejó en el comentario, observe que ahora está diferente, puede puede ver bajo su pregunta editar para hacer modificaciones a su pregunta o añadir informacion. Saludos

Comment: Puedes validar que tengas el archivo: `C:/Users/JOlivas/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/IBM.Data.DB2.DLL`

Comment: No está, C:\Users\JOlivas\.nuget\packages\IBM.Data.DB2\10.0.5.5\lib\net451 

en esa dirección aparece, lo copio a la del rumtime?

Comment: Hola, creo que te falta por instalar el driver para .NET, he actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

En ASP.NET Core se usa también una nueva versión de EF (EF Core) que por ahora da soporte a pocos motores de bases de datos pero sorprendentemente si tiene para bases de datos las DB2 ([aquí](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/ibm/index.html) tienes la documentación)

En esta misma documentación tienes [este enlace](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/sample_ef7_application_for_ibm_data_servers?lang=en) a una aplicación de ejemplo donde explican paso a paso como trabajar con una base de datos de IBM.

Si miras este código de ejemplo podrás ver que en el método `OnConfiguring` en la clase `IBMDbContext` se configura la base de datos a la que quieres acceder

```
class IBMDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseDb2(@"Server=servername:portno;Database=dbname;userid=uid;password=pwd");
    }
    ...
}
```

Realmente, la configuración de la conexión no se debería hacer ahí sino en el método `ConfigureServices` de la clase `Startup` haciendo algo así (no estoy 100% seguro de que funcione porque no lo he probado pero es como se hace con SqlServer o Sqlite):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Add EF services to the services container.
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .UseDb2()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 

             options.UseDb2(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
    ...
}
```

Por cierto, de los dos paquetes NuGuet que has puesto, tienes que usar el segundo ([EntityFramework.IBMDataServer 7.0.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.IBMDataServer/)) porque el primero es para la EF6

**Actualización (04/04/2016):**

Si se produce un error con el mensaje `Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' ...` podría indicar que no está instalado el Driver para .NET **"IBM Data Server Driver Package (Windows AMD64 and Intel EM64T) Version  10.5"**. Este driver se puede descargar desde [aquí](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/reg/pick.do?source=swg-idsdpds&lang=en_US)

Comment: No me funcionó, actualice la pregunta

Comment: Ese driver, no es necesario para ADO en las aplicaciones de ASP antiguas? porque tengo unas y nunca necesite instalar eso para que funcionaran. . .

Comment: @Jonhy.Olivas pues ahí me pillas porque yo no he trabajado nunca con Db2, lo he buscado en la documentación y centro de descarga. Lo he instalado y se corregía el error del ensamblado. ¿Cual usas tu desde .NET?

Comment: Me aparece un nuevo error, voy a actualizar la pregunta, en un comentario no alcanza.

Comment: @Jonhy.Olivas parece que tienes un problema de conectividad con la base de datos, podrías comprobar esta conectividad con como explican [aquí](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/r0058814.htm?cp=SSGU8G_11.50.0%2F4-11-2-5). Quizás proporcione mas información

Comment: @Jonhy.Olivas Sería ejecutando esto: `"C:\Archivos de programa\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\bin\testconn40" -dtc "database=sample;server=samplehost.domain.com:19766;uid=username;pwd=password"`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de cambiar el puerto, no lo indicas pero entiendo que no estás usando el puerto correcto por que te está informando que tú te conectas por TCP/IP mientras que el servidor espera sockets.

Los puertos son diferentes según el SO donde esté instalado DB2, 5000 para Windows pero para el AS400 usa el 446:

```
optionsBuilder.UseDb2(@"Server=x:446;Database=x;password=x;uid=x;")
```

Ahora bien, te adelanto que te saldrá otro error de licencia... Porque hay que utilizar un fichero de licencia descargado de IBM Passport con la consecuente compra de producto "DB2 connect unlimited edition for system i".